# Accessing button's variable from diffrent button (c# form)

Tags: c#

When i try to access bool variable from diffrent button like here:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Those my bool variable I want to access from the second button
        bool second = false , third = false , forth = false , fifth = false;
    }
       private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Here is where I try to access, but i can't.
            second = true;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are y sure about y just did, you declare a local variable in your first button nd you want to change it's value from an outside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set they as global variables.

```
bool second, third , forth , fifth = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Those my bool variable I want to access from the second button
    second = false; 
    third = false; 
    forth = false; 
    fifth = false;
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    second = true;
}
```